# Mapkit latitude and longitude to screen coordinates

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I have mapkit view, how i can convert  latitude and longitude to screen coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this method on your MKMapView object:

```
- (CGPoint)convertCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate toPointToView:(UIView *)view
```